# How to fetch different type of documents from a single collection - Mongodb - MongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I have a collection with different type of documents. Have different types of network tables & different type of entries of the tables in the single collection. depending of type document is different.I am trying to fetch these document based on some filter queries. As i have different documents i cant create a pojo with fixed fields because fields can vary according to the document so i can query like this.  I first want to fetch tables & later their entries based on table selection. Table document does not have "entry" key so i am using query like this - {type:{$exists:true},entry:{$exists:false}}

```
 return mongoTemplate.find(query, NetworkTable.class);
```

Have tried using Document.class instead of NetworkTable.class. Have tried with BasicQuery & Criteria but its not working. Query used to fetch tables only - Its working on mongodb shell.

```
         //BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery("{role:{$exists:true}}{type:{$exists:true},entry:{$exists:false}}");
          Query query = new Query();
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("entry").exists(flase));

          return mongoTemplate.find(query, Document.class,"user"); //user is collection name
```

Its giving below error when i use Document.class instead of NetworkTable.class -

```
{
    "timestamp": 1591963169373,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException",
    "message": "Failed to instantiate org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ",
}
```

Need quick help to resolve this.

Documents-

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ee2313e3694087f868576e2"
  },
  "_class": "org.json.simple.JSONObject",
  "_href": "https://1.1.1.1/config/xyz/2/table/ABC",
  "_display_name": " Table \"ABC\",
  "_state": "ok",
  "name": "ABC",
  "description": "",
  "type": "type1",
  "xyz": "2",
  "_short_name": "\"ABC\" "
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ee2313f3694087f868576e4"
  },
  "_class": "org.json.simple.JSONObject",
  "_href": "https://1.1.1.1/config/xyz/2/table/ABC/entry/1",
  "_display_name": "Entry 1",
  "apply-destination-number-manipulation": false,
  "type": "destination-tgid",
  "xyz": "2",
  "_children": [

  ],
  "entry": "1",
  "_state": "ok",
  "apply-traffic-group": false,
  "apply-source-number-manipulation": false,
  "name": "ABC",
  "action": "reject",
  "destination-sip-adjacency": {
    "_href": ""
  },
  "match-tgid": "any",
  "destination-tgid-manipulation": "none",
  "source-tgid-manipulation": "none",
  "_short_name": "1"
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5ee2313f3694087f86812344"
  },
  "_class": "org.json.simple.JSONObject",
  "_display_name": "Entry 1",
  "_href": "https://1.1.1.1/config/xyz/2/table/LLKORTELCSCS/entry/1",
  "_short_name": "1",
  "_state": "ok",
  "action": "complete",
  "apply-destination-number-manipulation": false,
  "apply-source-number-manipulation": false,
  "apply-traffic-group": false,
  "xyz": "2",
  "cost": 1,
  "destination-adjacency": {
    "_display_name": " \"LLKORTELCSCS_A\"",
    "_href": "https://1.1.1.1/config/adjacency/sip/LLKORTELCSCS_A",
    "_short_name": "LLKORTELCSCS_A"
  },
  "destination-tgid-manipulation": "none",
  "entry": "1",
  "name": "LLKORTELCSCS",
  "route-on-cost": "set-cost",
  "source-tgid-manipulation": "none",
  "type": "least-cost",
  "weight": 5
}
```

Comment: I think your Java query works fine (without having defined a `User` class). Please share a sample document from the `user` collection.

Comment: @prasad_ Thank you for the quick response. Actually i have given user as an example. i have a collection which contains networking table & their entries. Have edited the the main question. You can review the problem statement again.

Comment: I can't create the documents in my test environment with the fields: `_id` and the ones that has a value `"` escaped with a "\". So, I removed the those fields (the `_id`, `_short_name` and `_display_name`) and created the documents. I ran with Spring Data MongoDB v2.2.4 and MongoDB v4.2. The query ran without any errors.